# How to change all negative numbers to positive python?

Tags: python-3.x

In python 3, how can we change a list of numbers (such as 4, 1, -7, 1, -3) and change all of the negative signs into positive signs?

Comment: Python, like virtually all programming languages, has a built-in absolute value function. Just use it in a loop or a comprehension.

Comment: You would have found many results if you had googled "negative numbers to positive python"

Answer (score 3):

I think you are looking for the `abs` [function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#abs).